"Flutter App Compatibility Issue on Play Store"
Internal EARLY ACCESS S.S
EARLY ACCESS S.S
I successfully published my flutter application in the Internal test (version code 1). Testers could download the app without any problems. When it came to the closed test, I increased the version code and uploaded a new aab file (version code 2). For the devices used in the internal test, it gave an error that this version is not compatible with your device, but it can be downloaded without any problem on some devices. Why do I have this problem with the version in the closed test while it can be downloaded on all devices in the internal test, even though I have not made any changes in the source code?
My Flutter Doctor result:
tyb@macos-air learning_voices_for_babies % flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.19.6, on macOS 14.4.1 23E224 darwin-arm64, locale tr-TR)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 15.3)
[✗] Chrome - develop for the web (Cannot find Chrome executable at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome)
    ! Cannot find Chrome. Try setting CHROME_EXECUTABLE to a Chrome executable.
[✓] Android Studio (version 2023.1)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.89.0)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)
[✓] Network resources

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.

My AndroidManifest.xml file:
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <application
        android:label="Listen Kids: What is that?"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
    <!-- Required to query activities that can process text, see:
         https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility?hl=en and
         https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#ACTION_PROCESS_TEXT.

         In particular, this is used by the Flutter engine in io.flutter.plugin.text.ProcessTextPlugin. -->
    <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PROCESS_TEXT"/>
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
        </intent>
    </queries>
</manifest>

My Build.gradle file:
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
}

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}
def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}



android {
    namespace "com.example.learning_voices_for_babies"
    compileSdk flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.devast.listenkidswhatisthat"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
         // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
         // Signing with the debug keys for now,
         // so `flutter run --release` works.
          
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:2.0.1'

}

I thought it was from minSdk targetSdk and I installed minSdk 21 and targetSdk by changing it to 33-34, but it didn't work. I thought it was from the AppSign section, I did the request upload key reset in the play consol and reinstalled it again, but the result did not change.
My Pubspec.yaml file:
name: learning_voices_for_babies
description: "A new Flutter project."
# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `flutter pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number is used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
# In Windows, build-name is used as the major, minor, and patch parts
# of the product and file versions while build-number is used as the build suffix.
version: 1.1.3+13

environment:
  sdk: '>=3.3.0 <4.0.0'

# Dependencies specify other packages that your package needs in order to work.
# To automatically upgrade your package dependencies to the latest versions
# consider running `flutter pub upgrade --major-versions`. Alternatively,
# dependencies can be manually updated by changing the version numbers below to
# the latest version available on pub.dev. To see which dependencies have newer
# versions available, run `flutter pub outdated`.
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.6
  audioplayers: ^6.0.0
  video_player: ^2.8.2
  flutter_launcher_icons: "^0.13.1"

flutter_launcher_icons:
  background_color_ios: "#ffffff"
  remove_alpha_ios: true
  android: true
  ios: true
  adaptive_icon_background: "assets/logo_background.png"
  image_path_android: "assets/logo_foreground.png"
  adaptive_icon_foreground: "assets/logo_foreground.png"
  image_path_ios: "assets/logo.png"


dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  # The "flutter_lints" package below contains a set of recommended lints to
  # encourage good coding practices. The lint set provided by the package is
  # activated in the `analysis_options.yaml` file located at the root of your
  # package. See that file for information about deactivating specific lint
  # rules and activating additional ones.
  flutter_lints: ^3.0.0

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter packages.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - assets/
    - assets/sounds/
    - assets/sounds/nature/
    - assets/sounds/cars/
    - assets/sounds/animals/
    - assets/sounds/enstruman/
  #   - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages


My Pubspeck.lock file:
# Generated by pub
# See https://dart.dev/tools/pub/glossary#lockfile
packages:
  archive:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
      name: archive
      sha256: "22600aa1e926be775fa5fe7e6894e7fb3df9efda8891c73f70fb3262399a432d"
      url: "https://pub.dev"
    source: hosted
    version: "3.4.10"
  args:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
      name: args
      sha256: "7cf60b9f0cc88203c5a190b4cd62a99feea42759a7fa695010eb5de1c0b2252a"
      url: "https://pub.dev"
    source: hosted
    version: "2.5.0"
  async:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
      name: async
      sha256: "947bfcf187f74dbc5e146c9eb9c0f10c9f8b30743e341481c1e2ed3ecc18c20c"
      url: "https://pub.dev"
    source: hosted
    version: "2.11.0"
  audioplayers:
    dependency: "direct main"
    description:
      name: audioplayers
      sha256: "752039d6aa752597c98ec212e9759519061759e402e7da59a511f39d43aa07d2"
      url: "https://pub.dev"
    source: hosted
    version: "6.0.0"
  audioplayers_android:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
      name: audioplayers_android
      sha256: de576b890befe27175c2f511ba8b742bec83765fa97c3ce4282bba46212f58e4
      url: "https://pub.dev"
    source: hosted
    version: "5.0.0"
  audioplayers_darwin:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
      name: audioplayers_darwin
      sha256: e507887f3ff18d8e5a10a668d7bedc28206b12e10b98347797257c6ae1019c3b
      url: "https://pub.dev"
    source: hosted
    version: "6.0.0"
  audioplayers_linux:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
      name: audioplayers_linux
      sha256: "3d3d244c90436115417f170426ce768856d8fe4dfc5ed66a049d2890acfa82f9"
      url: "https://pub.dev"
    source: hosted
    version: "4.0.0"
  audioplayers_platform_interface:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
      name: audioplayers_platform_interface
      sha256: "6834dd48dfb7bc6c2404998ebdd161f79cd3774a7e6779e1348d54a3bfdcfaa5"
      url: "https://pub.dev"
    source: hosted
    version: "7.0.0"
  audioplayers_web:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
      name: audioplayers_web
      sha256: db8fc420dadf80da18e2286c18e746fb4c3b2c5adbf0c963299dde046828886d
      url: "https://pub.dev"
    source: hosted
    version: "5.0.0"
  audioplayers_windows:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
      name: audioplayers_windows
      sha256: "8605762dddba992138d476f6a0c3afd9df30ac5b96039929063eceed416795c2"
      url: "https://pub.dev"
    source: hosted
    version: "4.0.0"
  boolean_selector:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
      name: boolean_selector
      sha256: "6cfb5af12253eaf2b368f07bacc5a80d1301a071c73360d746b7f2e32d762c66"
      url: "https://pub.dev"
    source: hosted
    version: "2.1.1"
  characters:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
      name: characters
      sha256: "04a925763edad70e8443c99234dc3328f442e811f1d8fd1a72f1c8ad0f69a605"
      url: "https://pub.dev"
    source: hosted
    version: "1.3.0"
  checked_yaml:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
      name: checked_yaml
      sha256: feb6bed21949061731a7a75fc5d2aa727cf160b91af9a3e464c5e3a32e28b5ff
      url: "https://pub.dev"
    source: hosted
    version: "2.0.3"
  cli_util:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
      name: cli_util
      sha256: c05b7406fdabc7a49a3929d4af76bcaccbbffcbcdcf185b082e1ae07da323d19
      url: "https://pub.dev"
    source: hosted
    version: "0.4.1"
  clock:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
      name: clock
      sha256: cb6d7f03e1de671e34607e909a7213e31d7752be4fb66a86d29fe1eb14bfb5cf
      url: "https://pub.dev"
    source: hosted
    version: "1.1.1"
  collection:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
      name: collection
      sha256: ee67cb0715911d28db6bf4af1026078bd6f0128b07a5f66fb2ed94ec6783c09a
      url: "https://pub.dev"
    source: hosted
    version: "1.18.0"
  convert:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
      name: convert
      sha256: "0f08b14755d163f6e2134cb58222dd25ea2a2ee8a195e53983d57c075324d592"
      url: "https://pub.dev"
    source: hosted
    version: "3.1.1"
  crypto:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
      name: crypto
      sha256: ff625774173754681d66daaf4a448684fb04b78f902da9cb3d308c19cc5e8bab
      url: "https://pub.dev"
    source: hosted
    version: "3.0.3"
  csslib:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
      name: csslib
      sha256: "706b5707578e0c1b4b7550f64078f0a0f19dec3f50a178ffae7006b0a9ca58fb"
      url: "https://pub.dev"
    source: hosted
    version: "1.0.0"
  cupertino_icons:
    dependency: "direct main"
    description:
      name: cupertino_icons
      sha256: d57953e10f9f8327ce64a508a355f0b1ec902193f66288e8cb5070e7c47eeb2d
      url: "https://pub.dev"
    source: hosted
    version: "1.0.6"
  fake_async:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
      name: fake_async
      sha256: "511392330127add0b769b75a987850d136345d9227c6b94c96a04cf4a391bf78"
      url: "https://pub.dev"
    source: hosted
    version: "1.3.1"
  ffi:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
      name: ffi
      sha256: "493f37e7df1804778ff3a53bd691d8692ddf69702cf4c1c1096a2e41b4779e21"
      url: "https://pub.dev"
    source: hosted
    version: "2.1.2"
  file:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
      name: file
      sha256: "5fc22d7c25582e38ad9a8515372cd9a93834027aacf1801cf01164dac0ffa08c"
      url: "https://pub.dev"
    source: hosted
    version: "7.0.0"
  fixnum:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
      name: fixnum
      sha256: "25517a4deb0c03aa0f32fd12db525856438902d9c16536311e76cdc57b31d7d1"
      url: "https://pub.dev"
    source: hosted
    version: "1.1.0"
  flutter:
    dependency: "direct main"
    description: flutter
    source: sdk
    version: "0.0.0"
  flutter_launcher_icons:
    dependency: "direct main"
    description:
      name: flutter_launcher_icons
      sha256: "526faf84284b86a4cb36d20a5e45147747b7563d921373d4ee0559c54fcdbcea"
      url: "https://pub.dev"
    source: hosted
    version: "0.13.1"
  flutter_lints:
    dependency: "direct dev"
    description:
      name: flutter_lints
      sha256: e2a421b7e59244faef694ba7b30562e489c2b489866e505074eb005cd7060db7
      url: "https://pub.dev"
    source: hosted
    version: "3.0.1"
  flutter_test:
    dependency: "direct dev"
    description: flutter
    source: sdk
    version: "0.0.0"
  flutter_web_plugins:
    dependency: transitive
    description: flutter
    source: sdk
    version: "0.0.0"
  html:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
      name: html
      sha256: "3a7812d5bcd2894edf53dfaf8cd640876cf6cef50a8f238745c8b8120ea74d3a"
      url: "https://pub.dev"
    source: hosted
    version: "0.15.4"
  http:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
      name: http
      sha256: "761a297c042deedc1ffbb156d6e2af13886bb305c2a343a4d972504cd67dd938"
      url: "https://pub.dev"
    source: hosted
    version: "1.2.1"
  http_parser:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
      name: http_parser
      sha256: "2aa08ce0341cc9b354a498388e30986515406668dbcc4f7c950c3e715496693b"
      url: "https://pub.dev"
    source: hosted
    version: "4.0.2"
  image:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
      name: image
      sha256: "4c68bfd5ae83e700b5204c1e74451e7bf3cf750e6843c6e158289cf56bda018e"
      url: "https://pub.dev"
    source: hosted
    version: "4.1.7"
  js:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
      name: js
      sha256: c1b2e9b5ea78c45e1a0788d29606ba27dc5f71f019f32ca5140f61ef071838cf
      url: "https://pub.dev"
    source: hosted
    version: "0.7.1"
  json_annotation:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
      name: json_annotation
      sha256: b10a7b2ff83d83c777edba3c6a0f97045ddadd56c944e1a23a3fdf43a1bf4467
      url: "https://pub.dev"
    source: hosted
    version: "4.8.1"
  leak_tracker:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
      name: leak_tracker
      sha256: "78eb209deea09858f5269f5a5b02be4049535f568c07b275096836f01ea323fa"
      url: "https://pub.dev"
    source: hosted
    version: "10.0.0"
  leak_tracker_flutter_testing:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
      name: leak_tracker_flutter_testing
      sha256: b46c5e37c19120a8a01918cfaf293547f47269f7cb4b0058f21531c2465d6ef0
      url: "https://pub.dev"
    source: hosted
    version: "2.0.1"
  leak_tracker_testing:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
      name: leak_tracker_testing
      sha256: a597f72a664dbd293f3bfc51f9ba69816f84dcd403cdac7066cb3f6003f3ab47
      url: "https://pub.dev"
    source: hosted
    version: "2.0.1"
  lints:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
      name: lints
      sha256: cbf8d4b858bb0134ef3ef87841abdf8d63bfc255c266b7bf6b39daa1085c4290
      url: "https://pub.dev"
    source: hosted
    version: "3.0.0"
  matcher:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
      name: matcher
      sha256: d2323aa2060500f906aa31a895b4030b6da3ebdcc5619d14ce1aada65cd161cb
      url: "https://pub.dev"
    source: hosted
    version: "0.12.16+1"
  material_color_utilities:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
      name: material_color_utilities
      sha256: "0e0a020085b65b6083975e499759762399b4475f766c21668c4ecca34ea74e5a"
      url: "https://pub.dev"
    source: hosted
    version: "0.8.0"
  meta:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
      name: meta
      sha256: d584fa6707a52763a52446f02cc621b077888fb63b93bbcb1143a7be5a0c0c04
      url: "https://pub.dev"
    source: hosted
    version: "1.11.0"
  path:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
      name: path
      sha256: "087ce49c3f0dc39180befefc60fdb4acd8f8620e5682fe2476afd0b3688bb4af"
      url: "https://pub.dev"
    source: hosted
    version: "1.9.0"
  path_provider:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
      name: path_provider
      sha256: b27217933eeeba8ff24845c34003b003b2b22151de3c908d0e679e8fe1aa078b
      url: "https://pub.dev"
    source: hosted
    version: "2.1.2"
  path_provider_android:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
      name: path_provider_android
      sha256: "477184d672607c0a3bf68fbbf601805f92ef79c82b64b4d6eb318cbca4c48668"
      url: "https://pub.dev"
    source: hosted
    version: "2.2.2"
  path_provider_foundation:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
      name: path_provider_foundation
      sha256: "5a7999be66e000916500be4f15a3633ebceb8302719b47b9cc49ce924125350f"
      url: "https://pub.dev"
    source: hosted
    version: "2.3.2"
  path_provider_linux:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
      name: path_provider_linux
      sha256: f7a1fe3a634fe7734c8d3f2766ad746ae2a2884abe22e241a8b301bf5cac3279
      url: "https://pub.dev"
    source: hosted
    version: "2.2.1"
  path_provider_platform_interface:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
      name: path_provider_platform_interface
      sha256: "88f5779f72ba699763fa3a3b06aa4bf6de76c8e5de842cf6f29e2e06476c2334"
      url: "https://pub.dev"
    source: hosted
    version: "2.1.2"
  path_provider_windows:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
      name: path_provider_windows
      sha256: "8bc9f22eee8690981c22aa7fc602f5c85b497a6fb2ceb35ee5a5e5ed85ad8170"
      url: "https://pub.dev"
    source: hosted
    version: "2.2.1"
  petitparser:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
      name: petitparser
      sha256: c15605cd28af66339f8eb6fbe0e541bfe2d1b72d5825efc6598f3e0a31b9ad27
      url: "https://pub.dev"
    source: hosted
    version: "6.0.2"
  platform:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
      name: platform
      sha256: "12220bb4b65720483f8fa9450b4332347737cf8213dd2840d8b2c823e47243ec"
      url: "https://pub.dev"
    source: hosted
    version: "3.1.4"
  plugin_platform_interface:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
      name: plugin_platform_interface
      sha256: "4820fbfdb9478b1ebae27888254d445073732dae3d6ea81f0b7e06d5dedc3f02"
      url: "https://pub.dev"
    source: hosted
    version: "2.1.8"
  pointycastle:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
      name: pointycastle
      sha256: "79fbafed02cfdbe85ef3fd06c7f4bc2cbcba0177e61b765264853d4253b21744"
      url: "https://pub.dev"
    source: hosted
    version: "3.9.0"
  sky_engine:
    dependency: transitive
    description: flutter
    source: sdk
    version: "0.0.99"
  source_span:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
      name: source_span
      sha256: "53e943d4206a5e30df338fd4c6e7a077e02254531b138a15aec3bd143c1a8b3c"
      url: "https://pub.dev"
    source: hosted
    version: "1.10.0"
  sprintf:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
      name: sprintf
      sha256: "1fc9ffe69d4df602376b52949af107d8f5703b77cda567c4d7d86a0693120f23"
      url: "https://pub.dev"
    source: hosted
    version: "7.0.0"
  stack_trace:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
      name: stack_trace
      sha256: "73713990125a6d93122541237550ee3352a2d84baad52d375a4cad2eb9b7ce0b"
      url: "https://pub.dev"
    source: hosted
    version: "1.11.1"
  stream_channel:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
      name: stream_channel
      sha256: ba2aa5d8cc609d96bbb2899c28934f9e1af5cddbd60a827822ea467161eb54e7
      url: "https://pub.dev"
    source: hosted
    version: "2.1.2"
  string_scanner:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
      name: string_scanner
      sha256: "556692adab6cfa87322a115640c11f13cb77b3f076ddcc5d6ae3c20242bedcde"
      url: "https://pub.dev"
    source: hosted
    version: "1.2.0"
  synchronized:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
      name: synchronized
      sha256: "539ef412b170d65ecdafd780f924e5be3f60032a1128df156adad6c5b373d558"
      url: "https://pub.dev"
    source: hosted
    version: "3.1.0+1"
  term_glyph:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
      name: term_glyph
      sha256: a29248a84fbb7c79282b40b8c72a1209db169a2e0542bce341da992fe1bc7e84
      url: "https://pub.dev"
    source: hosted
    version: "1.2.1"
  test_api:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
      name: test_api
      sha256: "5c2f730018264d276c20e4f1503fd1308dfbbae39ec8ee63c5236311ac06954b"
      url: "https://pub.dev"
    source: hosted
    version: "0.6.1"
  typed_data:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
      name: typed_data
      sha256: facc8d6582f16042dd49f2463ff1bd6e2c9ef9f3d5da3d9b087e244a7b564b3c
      url: "https://pub.dev"
    source: hosted
    version: "1.3.2"
  uuid:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
      name: uuid
      sha256: cd210a09f7c18cbe5a02511718e0334de6559871052c90a90c0cca46a4aa81c8
      url: "https://pub.dev"
    source: hosted
    version: "4.3.3"
  vector_math:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
      name: vector_math
      sha256: "80b3257d1492ce4d091729e3a67a60407d227c27241d6927be0130c98e741803"
      url: "https://pub.dev"
    source: hosted
    version: "2.1.4"
  video_player:
    dependency: "direct main"
    description:
      name: video_player
      sha256: fbf28ce8bcfe709ad91b5789166c832cb7a684d14f571a81891858fefb5bb1c2
      url: "https://pub.dev"
    source: hosted
    version: "2.8.2"
  video_player_android:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
      name: video_player_android
      sha256: "4dd9b8b86d70d65eecf3dcabfcdfbb9c9115d244d022654aba49a00336d540c2"
      url: "https://pub.dev"
    source: hosted
    version: "2.4.12"
  video_player_avfoundation:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
      name: video_player_avfoundation
      sha256: "309e3962795e761be010869bae65c0b0e45b5230c5cee1bec72197ca7db040ed"
      url: "https://pub.dev"
    source: hosted
    version: "2.5.6"
  video_player_platform_interface:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
      name: video_player_platform_interface
      sha256: "236454725fafcacf98f0f39af0d7c7ab2ce84762e3b63f2cbb3ef9a7e0550bc6"
      url: "https://pub.dev"
    source: hosted
    version: "6.2.2"
  video_player_web:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
      name: video_player_web
      sha256: "8e9cb7fe94e49490e67bbc15149691792b58a0ade31b32e3f3688d104a0e057b"
      url: "https://pub.dev"
    source: hosted
    version: "2.2.0"
  vm_service:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
      name: vm_service
      sha256: b3d56ff4341b8f182b96aceb2fa20e3dcb336b9f867bc0eafc0de10f1048e957
      url: "https://pub.dev"
    source: hosted
    version: "13.0.0"
  web:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
      name: web
      sha256: "97da13628db363c635202ad97068d47c5b8aa555808e7a9411963c533b449b27"
      url: "https://pub.dev"
    source: hosted
    version: "0.5.1"
  win32:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
      name: win32
      sha256: "464f5674532865248444b4c3daca12bd9bf2d7c47f759ce2617986e7229494a8"
      url: "https://pub.dev"
    source: hosted
    version: "5.2.0"
  xdg_directories:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
      name: xdg_directories
      sha256: faea9dee56b520b55a566385b84f2e8de55e7496104adada9962e0bd11bcff1d
      url: "https://pub.dev"
    source: hosted
    version: "1.0.4"
  xml:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
      name: xml
      sha256: b015a8ad1c488f66851d762d3090a21c600e479dc75e68328c52774040cf9226
      url: "https://pub.dev"
    source: hosted
    version: "6.5.0"
  yaml:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
      name: yaml
      sha256: "75769501ea3489fca56601ff33454fe45507ea3bfb014161abc3b43ae25989d5"
      url: "https://pub.dev"
    source: hosted
    version: "3.1.2"
sdks:
  dart: ">=3.3.0 <4.0.0"
  flutter: ">=3.19.0"



If you are getting this error then the issue is in the SHA1 of your app. The already download version and the current one have different SHA1. Google Play store sign your app again when download, so it's SHA1 changes. Meaning the apk you are uploading and the apk you downloaded from play store will always have different SHA1. And that will throw incompatibility issue. Just delete the current app and download the latest one and it will work.

I did what you said. When I switched from the internal test version to the closed test version, the option to update the application appeared on google play. But when I enter the closed test version on the device where I have never downloaded the application before, it says this is not compatible with your device. The strange thing is that on another device that has never been downloaded, the download option appears.

Please check few things like if the the device is registered as testing device. Also check if the app is actually compatible with device. It is possible that some 3rd party sdk is not compatible with device. And your comment was not helpful. Your statement contradicts. You said it work for new device  but then you said it doesn't. Please add the steps you have done for solving the prblm.

The internal test version (version code: 1) can be downloaded without any problems on every phone.
Closed test version (version code:2) is not compatible with your device on some phones (not on all phones).
The only difference between the two test versions is that the version code is increased by one. The signatures are the same, the code itself is the same.

Add your pubspec.yaml file and device config where it is not working. Also compare pubspec.lock file for both version of your app. The prblm is in device compatibility I guess.

I uploaded the files you asked for, can you look again?

You should check in git commits of your repo for what part is changed to get better idea.

These issues occur more in Oneplus and MAUI devices. The reason is always in devices incompatibility. In flutter the packages you are using can hardly cause this issue. If it works for internal testing in one device but not for closed testing in same device, then check what have you changed. Like some version change Or have you added form factor for alpha testing in playstore.

I could not solve the problem and I chose create new application from the beginning and moved only the code (except Pubspec.yaml build.gradle etc.) to another project. I signed it and this time I did not release any version in the internal test, I only selected the closed test and released it. I will inform you if the problem persists after it is reviewed and given permission to publish. In the meantime, I contacted play console support. I stated the problem. If they find a solution, I will be here again, thank you very much.

I moved the application codes to the new project and re-signed the application and started the version code from 1. I created the application again from the application creation section in Google consalda, this time I only published a closed test and it works smoothly on all devices.
